# Is it OK to use normal approximation when doing Mann-Whitney test on small samples (n=5) with ties?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

We compare the distribution of samples with small sample size, in general 5 or 6 measurements per sample. It is frequent to have ties, so in R (at least not with the coin package) wilcox.test will use normal approximation to compute an exact p-value. Is it OK to do this in the case of such small sample sizes?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't use the asymptotic distribution and for small sample size the ties become a problem.

Comment: Thank you. How can I test if my samples have different distributions? This work will be published, can you suggest a piece of work I can cite as a demonstration, or elaborate a little more so I can convince reviewers by myself?

Comment: Why not using exact rank tests plus a clean multiple testing strategy?

Comment: Have you looked at the wilcox.exact function, or wilcox_test in the coin package?

Comment: OK so from coin package I can use wilcox_test with distribution='exact' to get exact p-values. @Michael M: I don't understand what is a "clean multiple testing strategy". I don't know the shift algorithm of Streitberg and Rohmel used in coin::wilcox_test, are you aware of a pseudo-code description of it? It's written in C in the coin package and I can't read this.